# Does PayPal recycle PayerIds? I'm linking private information to PayerIds

Tags: paypal

I'm changing my online store right now.  I decided to remove accounts altogether... so that the users can go straight to paypal express checkout and just pay.

I'm doing the paypal part first, then i redirect back to my site to let them fill in a shipping address, billing address, and then review the information before submitting the order.

So far i noticed that Paypal always sends back the same PayerID if you are logging into a paypal account.  Also, if you don't log into a paypal account (and just punch in your credit card), it will return the same payerID for that credit card in the future.

Is it safe for me to keep track of shipping address in order to create an address book and link them to the payerID?  That way, returning paypal customers will be able to select a saved address...

Does paypal recycle these IDs... or are they always going to be unique and there is no fear of me showing someone elses information to another customer...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PayerID's are unique to each account. They won't ever change for the same account.

Comment: I'm more worried that 2 different people will get the same payerid ... can one guy have one payerid now and another guy have the same payerid 2 years in the future: